# CSS-Grid begin with next column

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a 3 column css grid with content. I try to make it like that: 
If content is too much, it should go to next column.

But I couldn't make it work. Do you have any hints?

```css
.details {
        background: #000;
        color: #fff;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
        grid-template-rows: repeat(1, 100%);
        grid-column-gap: 2px;
        grid-row-gap: 2px;
        .detail {
          text-align: left;
          padding: 10px;
        }
}
```

[image: Css Grid Columns]

Comment: This would fall under Regions/Fragmentation, which is not released yet. You can however use [multi-column](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Columns/Using_multi-column_layouts) to achieve the desired result, but you won't have rows, as this does not leverage CSS grid.

Comment: That's it. Perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You may use column CSS and floating pseudo elements to push content at the most towards the first columns :

possible examples **to run and test in fullpage**  :

- 3 columns from column-count

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  column-count: 3;
}

div p::before {
  content: '';
  padding-bottom: 90vh;
  float: left;
}


/* extra styling */

div {
  column-rule: double gray;
  margin: 1em;
  border: solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: rgb(243, 241, 121);
}

div h1,
p {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 1em auto;
  text-indent: 1em;
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Column CSS</h1>
  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
    Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
    Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
```

- or setting `column-width` instead `column-count` for a responsive behavior:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  column-width: 18em;
}

div p::before {
  content: '';
  padding-bottom: 90vh;
  float: left;
}


/* extra styling */

div {
  column-rule: double gray;
  margin: 1em;
  border: solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: rgb(243, 241, 121);
}

div h1,
p {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 1em auto;
  text-indent: 1em;
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Column CSS</h1>
  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
    Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
    Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
```

probably not as perfect as you imagine : [codepen demo to play with](https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/qBdagYv)